# Is Reactjs based on Object Orient concept?

Tags: javascript, oop, reactjs

I am starting to use Reactjs, and coming from a OO (Java) background I was curious if we can use React in a true Object Oriented fashion with true inheritance and composition.

USE CASE: We are creating React components in a library for our developers to reuse. Can we design this in an Object Oriented fashion? For example, can I have a generic Input text field, with some basic styles/behaviors, then have another MyInput field that extends Input that is able to leverage the properties and behaviors from Input?

It seems that most of what I've learned React uses states and reducers within the Application itself to manage everything; which to me seems like it's missing the point of the power of OO design. But maybe I'm wrong. Any information would be most helpful

Comment: Javascript is object oriented!

Comment: i think react is predicated on the assumption that OOP is not a very desirable design pattern for web apps, and attempts to overcome many of the complications resulting from lots of things extending lots of things and talking to lots of other things...

Comment: Google "component composition" and read about that -- it's a much better approach than inheritance in my opinion.

Comment: Please remove the "*true*" from your question, it makes one feel a need to educate you :-)

Comment: React started out as object oriented, but with time it evolved to functional paradigm favoring composition over inheritance. After years working with OOP and I find functional approach and composition superior!

Answer (score 29):

First of all I would like to tell you that **React** is based on **Javascript** which is obviously object oriented (but not exactly similar to languages such as Java, C++, and many other traditional Object Oriented languages
).

React itself does not enforces any object oriented technique but
React components are totally reusable. You can create generic components from very simple input text box, labels to complex one and can be reused many times.

If you are coming from **Java** world, then I would suggest you to use **Javascript es6** to get taste of class in somewhat similar way.

A sample React component in **Javascript es6**

```
class Text extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>{this.props.children}</p>;
  }
}

React.render(<Text>Hello World</Text>, document.body);
```

See how **inheritance** is working here

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    toString() {
        return '(' + this.x + ', ' + this.y + ')';
    }
}

class CPoint extends Point {
    constructor(x, y, color) {
        super(x, y);
        this.color = color;
    }
    toString() {
        return super.toString() + ' in ' + this.color;
    }
}
```

All code you see is in Javascript!

For React you can divide your application to have  **Presentational components** and **Container components** for better re-usability and structuring.

- **Presentational components :**
  mainly concerned with receiving the data via props and displaying them. They don’t specify how the data is loaded or mutated and don't have their own states.

**Example**

```
const Text = ({ children = 'Hello World!' }) => <p>{children}</p>
```

- **Container components:**
  passes the data and behavior to presentational or other container components. They have their own states.You can generate the data here and pass it to presentational components.

**Example**

```
class Contacts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
          message:"new message"
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div><Text children={this.state.message}/></div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would suggest stay away from Mixins.
**Mixins aren't supported in ES6 classes.**

Comment: "First of all I would like to tell you that React is based on Javascript which is obviously object oriented."  -- I believe this statement is misleading, many modern JS books are providing that JS has a lot of constructs which allow developers to use(misuse) JS as an object oriented language, but more correctly it is a objects linked to other objects language as specified in the You Don't Know JS Series

Comment: @AranFreel: **but more correctly it is a objects linked to other objects language**, correct, but `OLOO` is also Object Oriented.

Comment: Javascript by itself is *not* object-oriented.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to create [mixins](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) to share functionality between components. Inheritance force tight coupling of components and in the long run this can be contraproducente.